# Python Pandas Get Unique Count of Column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python, lots of JS experience and SQL, and everything I've found so far is counting number of uniques for each value, but all I want is a count of unique values in the column "Team"

```
uniqueCount= teamTable.groupby('Team').nunique()
print uniqueCount
```

But this only gives me the error "AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'nunique'"

Thought this would be simple enough to find, but honestly can't find the function

```
Date        ID  Team
1/1/2017    A   Bears
1/1/2017    A   Packers
1/1/2017    A   Lions
1/1/2017    B   Lions
1/3/2017    A   Packers
```

Comment: `len(df.Team.unique())`

Comment: wow, length of the unique values of the column, TY sir

Comment: You're most welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get that with:

```
len(df.Team.unique())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Series.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
print (df.Team.nunique())
3
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `np.unique`

```
np.unique(df.Team.values).size

3
```

[image]

---

Followup to @Jeff's comment.  He was spot on, @Bernies answer scales the best with my crude test.  Might be indistinguishable form @jezrael's over all problem types.

[image]

Comment: you will see that these scale very differently np.unique sorts

Comment: @Jeff, yep.  I was too quick and dirty on the timing... however, are you saying `pd.Series.unique` and `pd.Series.nunique` do **not** sort?

Comment: @Jeff tyvm... I'll be leveraging that information extensively.

Comment: thanks guys, I will be testing all these out often over the coming weeks!